# Bitwise operations in C

Tags: c

This code compiles fine, but when I try to run it, it fails.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int c = 4;
    int b = 5;
    int a = a & b;
    printf(a);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't define a `test` function, or you don't call `func`.

Comment: "it fails" is awfully vague.   What is it doing?  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Aside from all the other stuff mentioned already, if `func()` is supposed to check whether `x` is a power of two or not, then you need to check for negative values of `x` in order to catch the case where it is `INT_MIN`.

Comment: The code that is showing now is not even REMOTELY close to the code you first posted.  What is this?

Comment: So, you totally changed the content of the question, without saying anything...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `printf` is the format string, a `char*`. Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for more information about constructing the format string.

```
printf(a);
```

should be:

```
printf("%d", a);
```

Otherwise `a` will be treated as the address of the start of a string, and cause undefined behaviour when it's dereferenced (there's a good chance it'll crash).

Also, I'm assuming that the above code isn't the exact code you're talking about, since it won't compile as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing what you exactly want to do, you program would actually fail (compile and runtime).

1. No Header files included so `return (EXIT_SUCCESS);` would give a compile error.
2. `printf(a);` is wrong, no format specifier. Should actually be `printf("%d",a);`
3. No forward declaration for `int func( int x )`.
4. Finally it seems you wanted to call `func` but ended up calling `test`

Answer (score 2):

`printf` takes a `char *, ...`, not an `int`. I think your code should be:

```
printf("%d", a);
```

Also, your function names, `test` and `func`, don't match. But I don't think that's the issue :)